# Cannot execute CTE query via Azure DataBricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to execute CTE query via data bricks getting syntax error for SQL query. Is there any other to use CTE from Data bricks?

Thanks in Advance .

pushdown_query = """(WITH t(x, y) AS (SELECT 1, 2)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2) as Test """
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)

Error:-
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword WITH."

[image]

Comment: I have same problem described in this note, working on premise that parameter format is problem. The param should be query or dbtable. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the  `as test` syntax:

```
WITH t(x, y) AS (SELECT 1, 2) SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2
```

This will work.

Comment: OK, are you running against a SQL Server, not Spark SQL?  If so, remove the outer brackets - I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried like below but getting same error.

pushdown_query =""" WITH t(x, y) AS (SELECT 1, 2) SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2 """
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)

Comment: What database and version are you running against?

Comment: I'm running this on Azure SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible using spark.read jdbc. When you use `dbtable` or `query` parameters, effect is to insert your SQL code as a subquery inside larger SELECT statement.

Spark docs for dbtable param are poor, IMHO, but you can see where this heading in `query` doc.

```
As an example, spark will issue a query of the following form to the JDBC Source.

SELECT <columns> FROM (<user_specified_query>) spark_gen_alias
```

The thing we specify gets turned into a subquery.

Add that with the fact that a WITH clause must not be included in a subquery. I'm looking for proof of that claim in the Microsoft docs.

Closest I can find is in doc referred to above,
which says WITH must be followed by single SELECT statement. https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-migrate-code.md

Answer (score -1):

I think CTE functionality is stripped out of Azure SQL Server, which is also known as Synapse.  You may be able to re-write some of your queries to do what you need, without using the standard CTE syntax.

These links should shed some light on the situation.

https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-migrate-code.md

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server

Comment: The second doc says CTE partially supported.